# Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid on IBM Thinkpad T41

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, livecd

I tried to boot my T41 from a Ubuntu Lucid liveCD and it worried me.

The white text on violet background had green pixels around it.
After the splashscreen went away Ubuntu popped an alert that the installer had some errors and will now run live.
The live system worked fine I guess...

Did anybody experience such behaviour?

Comment: "installer had some errors..." - WHAT errors? Maybe they do mean something and are not put there only to tease users?

Comment: Nope, they didn't say anything. [BTW sorry for the delay]

Answer (score 2):

Yes I experienced this too on my t42 when running the installer - and on booting the live cd - but after the install/update it worked fine.

Comment: Thanx. I can get down to some upgrading in August, so I didn't try it yet. I'm glad it will work :)